# Extjs 4 - form with column layout does not margin fields

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

Here is my view:

```
Ext.define('NG.view.order.Header', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.orderheader',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    layout: 'column',
    defaults: {
        columnWidth: .33,
        border: false
    },
    config: {
        order: null
    },

    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;

        me.items = me.createItems();

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.setOrder(config.order);
    },

    // creates this view items.
    createItems: function () {
        var items = [{
            //column 1
            layout: 'form',
            defaultType: 'displayfield',
            defaults: {
                margin:'0 0 15 0'
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'No',
                name: 'orderNumber'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Ver',
                name: 'version'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Date',
                name: 'orderDate',
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer(Date.patterns.defaultFormat)
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Amount',
                name: 'totalAmount'
            }]

        }, {
            //column 2
            layout: 'form',
            defaultType: 'displayfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Supplier',
                name: 'vendorName'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Supplier No',
                name: 'vendorDuns'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Customer',
                name: 'customerName'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Buyer',
                name: 'orderBuyerName'
            }]
        }]

        return items;
    }
});
```

As you can see I have set a margin on the first column fields.

Its seems this value is ignored .

Is this a known issue ??

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I see you have a margin bottom set on all fields inside the container (column 1) with `layout:'form'`. This doesn't match your question. So what do you expect?

Comment: I excpect to see a margin of 10 px for each field.

Comment: this is my question, I do not see it. it has no effect.

Comment: I tried adding the same margin in my own application, and it worked just fine on fields inside a FieldSet. I don't know what the default class of your form layout container is, but you might want to explicitly define the xtype, to make sure you are getting what you are expecting. Same with the fields.